# Laravel file upload Google Cloud Storage

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I'm using react js with laravel. Im making an api call to laravel and sending it the form data which also have files. Now I want those files to be uploaded on google cloud storage bucket. I have been searching for solution for a while but can't find anything that fully explains how to handle google cloud storage bucket in laravel. In some solutions they already have the file in laravel storage but I want to directly upload it from $request object.

API Call:

```
export const uploadToGCS = async (name, id, files) => {
const data = new FormData();
data.append("name", name);
data.append("id", id);
data.append("files", files);
const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/upload_to_GCS`, {
  method: "POST",
  body: data,
  headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
});
```

Comment: basically, I'd love to know if you installed google cloud storage? As you know, to upload to bucket, you need initialize, bucket base, key, body, acl. For body, you can use file buffer, not file. So you don't need to create a file. You can directly upload the file buffer. does this help you?

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-cloud-storage